# Avoiding incrementing in if statement in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I would like to avoid incrementing and decrementing in if-statement since there is a segmentation fault  error in the following code while checking conditions (if we start with p = 1 and k = 1 for example):

```
if (((heights[k--][p--] < heights[k][p]) || (heights[k--][p--] == heights[k][p])) &&
        ((heights[k--][p++] < heights[k][p]) || (heights[k--][p++] == heights[k][p])) &&
        ((heights[k++][p--] < heights[k][p]) || (heights[k++][p--] == heights[k][p])) &&
        ((heights[k++][p++] < heights[k][p]) || (heights[k++][p++] == heights[k][p]))){
                    width[k][p] = 3;
    }
```

For example, the second check fails with k = -1.
I would like to check neighbouring elements of a two-dimensional array `heights` in an if-statement and than run some logic in case it was true.

How can I optimise it and generally rewrite it to make it look (and work) better? I haven't found any information on it.

Comment: Can you replace all instances of `k--` with `k-1`, and all instances of `k++` with `k+1`, and so on?  It's hard to say what to do, since it's not obvious what behavior you want your program to exhibit.

Comment: Undefined behavior-ahoy. Can you explain what's wrong, for example with simply `heights[k-1][p-1]`, for example? What do you expect to accomplish by actually doing all of this incrementing or decrementing?

Comment: Also seems like many of them could be combined to some `(...)<=(...)` rather than `(...)<(...) || (...)==(...)`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I would like to check neighbouring elements of a two-dimensional array in an if-statement and than run some logic in case it was true.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, thank you, it really works.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep, yes, it was obvious, but I didn't notice:) Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have indicated, replacing 'k--' with 'k-1' and 'k++' with 'k+1' for all 'k' and 'p' variables may resolve the segmentation error. 'k+1' is a reference to the next array index after 'k', while 'k++' increments the value of 'k' after it's used. It's also good programming practice to avoid using expressions as arguments.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

To clean up the code, you could also simplify the logical OR by replacing '<' with '<='.

```
if ((heights[k-1][p-1] <= heights[k][p]) &&
    (heights[k-1][p+1] <= heights[k][p]) &&
    (heights[k+1][p-1] <= heights[k][p]) &&
    (heights[k+1][p+1] <= heights[k][p])){
        width[k][p] = 3;
    }
```